# Resolving fatal error Uncaught pcrov\JsonReader\Parser\ParseException (php json)

Tags: php, json

I am employing a [JSON pull parser for PHP 7](https://github.com/pcrov/JsonReader) to extract data from huge **25GB** json file. Here is [my dummy json file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B0MjygvBH6bsdTN5eHJoZHZMeG8/view?usp=sharing).
Data extraction works fine until `Line 153731` of the json file, and then I received this error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught pcrov\JsonReader\Parser\ParseException: Line 153731: Unexpected 'u'. in 
 C:\xampp\htdocs\json\pcrov\vendor\pcrov\jsonreader\src\Parser\Lexer.php:134 
 Stack trace: 
#0 C:\xampp\htdocs\json\pcrov\vendor\pcrov\jsonreader\src\Parser\Lexer.php(97): pcrov\JsonReader\Parser\Lexer->consumeLiteral('ull') 
#1 [internal function]: pcrov\JsonReader\Parser\Lexer->getIterator() 
#2 C:\xampp\htdocs\json\pcrov\vendor\pcrov\jsonreader\src\Parser\Parser.php(180): IteratorIterator->next() 
#3 C:\xampp\htdocs\json\pcrov\vendor\pcrov\jsonreader\src\Parser\Parser.php(152): pcrov\JsonReader\Parser\Parser->parsePair() 
#4 C:\xampp\htdocs\json\pcrov\vendor\pcrov\jsonreader\src\Parser\Parser.php(205): pcrov\JsonReader\Parser\Parser->parseObject() 
#5 C:\xampp\htdocs\json\pcrov\vendor\pcrov\jsonreader\src\Parser\Parser.php(123): pcrov\JsonReader\Parser\Parser->parseValue() 
#6 C:\xampp\htdocs\json\pcrov\vendor\pcrov\jsonreader\src\Parser\Parser.php(202): pcrov\JsonReader\Parser\Parser->parseArray() 
#7 C:\xampp\htdocs\json\pcrov\vendor\ in C:\xampp\htdocs\json\pcrov\vendor\pcrov\jsonreader\src\Parser\Lexer.php on line 134
```

I have googled and combed stackoverflow to know how to solve the problem, but has been unsuccessful.

Here is my code:

```
 <?php
 require_once 'C:/xampp/htdocs/json/pcrov/vendor/autoload.php';
 use \pcrov\JsonReader\JsonReader;
 ini_set("max_execution_time", 0);
 $reader = new JsonReader();
 $reader->open("myjsonfile.json");
 $fo = fopen("mycsv.csv", "w" );
 fputs($fo, "name, ultimateHoldingCompany".PHP_EOL);                                                    
 while($reader->read()) {
  $name = null;
  $uhcName = null;  
  if ($reader->read("entityName")){
    $name = null;
    $entityName = $reader->value();
  }

  if ($reader->read("ultimateHoldingCompany")){     
    $uhcName = null;
    $ultimateHoldingCompany = $reader->value();
    if (empty($ultimateHoldingCompany)){
        $uhcName = null;
    }
    else {
        $uhcName = $ultimateHoldingCompany[0]['name'];
    }

    //print_r($uhcName); die;

    }

   fputs($fo,  $entityName.",".$uhcName.PHP_EOL);
  }
 $reader->close();
 ?>
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Your dummy file appears to be a link to a JPG image ~ `Capture.JPG`

Comment: Oh Sorry. It was an oversight. I have corrected it.

Answer (score -1):

I solved the problem by splitting the json file into smaller chunks.